# Error CS0246 when launching C# web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I am developing a WEB API 2 project and I am trying to set up a basic authentication system on my REST server. 
I'm having issues with an error when I launch my application and I don't find the origin of this error.

**Class code :**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace CalypsoWebApplication.App_Code
{
    public class ResultWithChallenge : IHttpActionResult
    {
        private readonly System.Web.Http.IHttpActionResult next;

        public ResultWithChallenge(IHttpActionResult next)
        {
            this.next = next;
        }

        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(
                                    CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var res = await next.ExecuteAsync(cancellationToken);
            if (res.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
            {
                res.Headers.WwwAuthenticate.Add(
                   new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", null));
            }

            return res;
        }
    }
}
```

**Erreur au lancement :**

Message d'erreur du compilateur: CS0246: Le type ou le nom d'espace de noms 'HttpResponseMessage' est introuvable (une directive using ou une référence d'assembly est-elle manquante ?)

English translation : type or namespace 'HttpResponseMessage' cannot be found, is a using directive or an assembly reference missing ?

Erreur source:
Ligne 22 :         }
Ligne 23 : 
Ligne 24 :         public async Task ExecuteAsync(
Ligne 25 :                                     CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Ligne 26 :         {
Fichier source: e:\Users\mehin\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Calypso\CalypsoWebApplication\App_Code\ResultWithChallenge.cs    Ligne: 24

Whe looking on https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/w7xf6dxs.aspx the possibles sources of this error, I still don't understand why it happens.

- Target Framework .NET 4.5
- In my project references, I have "System.Net.Http" which targets System.NetNHttp.dll, version 4.0.0.0
- When trying to prefix HttpResponseMessage with System.Net.http, the error still occurs.
- When cleaning and building my solution in Visual Studio 2013, I don't get any error. I only get it when i launch the application.

I don't know what else I could add, don't hesitate to ask for more details.

Comment: if you are using local IIS then Application pool must run on ASP.Net 4.0 instead of 2.0, Please check

Comment: A C# compile error at runtime (and use of "App_Code" in the namespace) would indicate you have a Web Site project. It is not clear that this is possible (certainly Web App projects are supported but then there is no runtime complication of C# code files).

Comment: When i execute the project I have a generated web site which provides the API's avaible ressources at localhost:port/Help. This is the only website content that I have. I did put in App_Code the classes that expose tools comonly used over the project (authentication, security, tracing ...). Hayat might have spotted the problem, I am currently looking where to check the version of the framework used by IIS Express.

Comment: Still did not found how to make it work using IIS Express but it works in a standard IIS on Windows Server. This is not convenient for debugging, i'd be interested if anyone can provide some help to configure IIS Express to use Framework 4.0